# Automation tests for Unity engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for tool which can help to create some tests in Unity.
Yes, I know there are the "unity test tools". But it's for programmers mostly.
I need something for testers like selenium

Comment: Unity isn't a browser, I'm afraid. What kind of tests do you want to do? What do you want to achieve with the tests?

Comment: Why Unity test tools does not good for you?

Comment: And for more CI testing you cant set up Jenkis.

Comment: I undestand that is not a browser))
but selenium gives you an oppornity to write tests without good programming skills. Maybe I can find same something for Unity.

Well, its a game. In general I need a chance to push button, click QTE whats all

Answer (score 1):

Since unity is a diverse game engine that can be used to develop games in any genre or style there is no generic way of automatically testing them.

Without being good at programming all you can do for performance testing is to play the game and find areas that fluctuate in framerate and try to narrow down what scripts or game objects are causing the issue. You can use the [Profiler Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) to really help with that.

You could make scenes that run automatically with set things that happen in each one and then run them between builds and compare how well they do but I don't think thats what you're after.

Most of the time though testers in games just play the game or anything that engineering gives them and try to break it by getting the game to show unexpected behaviour. Once some issues are found it goes back to the guy that made it and the process is repeated... there is a [good podcast on testing here](http://thedebuglog.com/2015/07/09/episode-5-eating-your-own-dogfood/) on how testing is usually done in video games (from a developer's perspective).

Hope this helped